# Calculate the availavable time based on the properties in the object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this kind of json.

```
var meetings = [
  {
    id: '1',
    start_time: "2020-11-15T08:30:00+00:00",
    end_time: "2020-11-15T14:15:00+00:00"
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    start_time: "2020-11-15T19:30:00+00:00",
    end_time: "2020-11-15T20:30:00+00:00"
  },
];
```

So two meetings first one: 08:30 - 14:15 second: 19:30-20:30

There are 24 availavable hours for working so:

```
start_time = '00:00:00';
end_time = '23:59:00';
```

but in the format that i need would be

```
var start_time = '2020-11-15T00:00:00+00:00';
var end_time = '2020-11-15T23:59:00+00:00';
```

How can i calculate the avalavable hours depening on the already maked meetings? So because the first meeting is from 08:30 - 14:15 and the second 19:30-20:30 i will need json with the following result with the available hours:

```
[
  {
    start_time:'2020-11-15T00:00:00+00:00',
    end_time:'2020-11-15T08:30:00+00:00'
  },

  {
    start_time:'2020-11-15T14:15:00+00:00',
    end_time:'2020-11-15T19:30:00+00:00'
  },

  {
    start_time:'2020-11-15T20:30:00+00:00',
    end_time:'2020-11-15T23:59:00+00:00'
  }
]
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277348/how-to-calculate-free-available-time-based-on-array-values

Comment: It does not help because the date properties are not as mine :(

Comment: This answer could be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980014/how-can-i-calculate-the-time-between-2-dates-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

Use something like https://momentjs.com/ or https://date-fns.org/ if you like FP for parsing and formatting.
And for calculations maybe convert and work with timestamps and then back to preferred format for display.